# How to get Type name of a variable on Arduino

Tags: serial, variables, data-type

I found this [post](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/3079/how-to-retrieve-the-data-type-of-a-variable) and implemented the code in a separate classed and then passed different variables to it in an attempt to get the type name printed to serial.

The code compiled and worked fine but i get the following strange output:

```
For type int I get Fn on the serial monitor
For String I get ;y on the serial monitor
```

If I don't make a type using `MAKE_TYPE_INFO(type)` then try `TYPE_NAME()` I don't get `unknown` printed on the serial monitor. I get `fÝ`.

All this weirdness is consistent and I could use it to make decisions based on type but why do that if their is a solution.

Comment: Can you show us your full code? The example you link to works fine for me.

Comment: Also, are you sure you don't just have the wrong baud rate selected?

Comment: `I could use it to make decisions based on type` - why do you even need to?